# Returning large multidimensional array from c++ dll to vb

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, dll, multidimensional-array

I am writing a dll in c++ that will be returning a large multidimensional array of doubles to the calling VB executable. To begin with it will be 3 dimensions but will eventually increase to up to 11 dimensions.

How should this be done?
I just assume it would be a bad idea allocating on the stack.

I imagined this would be done as follows (3D case):

```
__declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall ***funcRet3Darr(double var1, double *var2, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3)
{
  double ***retarr = new double **[dim1];
  for (int i = 0; i<dim1; i++)
  {
    retarr[i] = new double *[dim2];
    for (int j = 0;j<dim2; j++)
      retarr[i][j] = new double [dim3];
  }

  // code to fill the values in retarr

  return retarr;
}
```

BUT (Question 2): what happens to the created pointer `retarr` in the dll? Does it become a memory problem if the c++ function is called multiple times? Does it need to be deleted in the dll function? (How would that be done???)

Comment: Use a linear array, and handle the indexing manually

Comment: I have thought of that but it would be nice if there was a way..

Comment: I think that's the easiest way